# PsExec & Process Through C# Not Showing Output

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd, psexec

Apparently PsExec is working. This code works. When executed, it never returns errors. But only SOMETIMES does it return output, and when it does return output, it is always~ the first line.
And the first line of ipconfig is "Windows IP Configuration" and the error box shows "ipconfig returned with the error code 0".
If you replace REMOTEPC with a local IP, it will run and you can see the cmd briefly flash with the information. So it works.

I should add that I believe the reason is that after executing the PsExec, it doesn't "exit". So WaitForExit never happens. When you click X out of the cmd window, the boxes show up. Sometimes with the output mentioned, or blank.

But it never outputs the entire thing for some blasted reason! Its never reading to the end.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PsExec.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\REMOTEPC -u USER -p PASS -s ipconfig /all";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        //p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        p.Start();


        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

       //Tried this method of getting the output too
       // while (!p.HasExited)
        //{
         //   output += p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
       // }

        string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        p.WaitForExit();

        MessageBox.Show(output);
        MessageBox.Show(error);


    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812637/issues-with-running-a-psexec-process-from-code?rq=1

Comment: I recommend piping the output into a file that you can read a moment later.