# Process.Start does not output the full output

Tags: c#, .net, process, psexec, citrix

I have a process P, which calls the PSEXEC executable, and passes it an argument. My issue is that the output from my C# program is not the same from when I call exactly the same command directly into a command prompt.

Here is the output I expect (when ran from CMD):

```
Server Name           Server Load
--------------------  ------------
601CTXD04             0
601CTXD05             0
...
601CTXP03             0
```

And here is the actual output (when ran from my program):

```
Server Name           Server Load
--------------------  ------------
601CTXD04             0
```

So when I run the command from my C# program, I only get 1 server. I call the process the following way :

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = cServer.psexec; //Path to the PSEXEC executable
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-accepteula \\\\601ctxp01 qfarm /load /continue";
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string[] lines = Regex.Split(output, "\\r\\n");
```

I really do not understand why, the exact same command ran from CMD does not give the same output when ran from a C# process. Please let me know what I am doing wrong as I am currently oblivious to my mistake.

Comment: try to add  `p.WaitForExit() ` after  `p.Start() `

Comment: Do not use p.WaitForExit after p.Start()! if the redirected output writes enough text to fill the stream you will have a deadlock condition and the program will hang. You can either use p.WaitForExit(int32) or call it after you read the output.

Comment: The advise to not call `WaitForExit()` immediately after calling `Start()` is correct. However, there's no point in calling `WaitForExit()` at all here. `ReadToEnd()` won't return until the stream is closed, which won't happen until the process has exited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue was with PsExec itself (a Sysinternal utility) as I have tried an alternative called PAExec and the same command works fine, so I am using this one in my code instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `p.WaitForExit()` after `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`, otherwise you won't get all of the output from the process. Don't put it directly after `p.Start()` - you may get a deadlock. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have added `p.WaitForExit()` after `string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` but it does exactly the same thing - I only get 1 line of output.

Comment: Is there any output on p.StandardError?

Comment: I have also tried adding `p.WaitForExit()` before the ReadToEnd, but it gives the same thing (just one output instead of all)

Comment: Error code 0 doesn't necessarily mean no output on standard error. Redirecting psexec output seems generally flaky, maybe try redirect to file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812637/issues-with-running-a-psexec-process-from-code?rq=1

Comment: The error code 0 comes from the qfarm command, not psexec itself. I could redirect to a file and then read the file, but that seems like a workaround, not a fix. Plus it's way more hassle to output to a file and then work the data, then simply outputting into a string as I am doing right now. If that's the only way to fix this, then I'll do that, but I doubt it is since I have other commands using the psexec utility and they all work well.

Comment: I have tried leaving `CreateNoWindow` to false, and looked at the output. It works. So when I have `RedirectStandardOutput = true`, that's when I only have one line

Comment: This answer is not correct. The `ReadToEnd()` method will block until the end of the stream is reached. Adding a call (to anything) _after_ the call to `ReadToEnd()` has no effect on what `ReadToEnd()` returns.

Comment: @MrRoy: it sounds as though the executable you're using is using stdout in some non-standard way. What this might be, I can't say. Unless you can come up with a code example others can actually try, the odds of someone else being able to figure out the problem are low. Is the "psexec.exe" program you're using the same PsExec.exe from Sysinternals? If so, the lack of a window might be confusing it.

Comment: Yes this is the PsExec.exe from Sysinternals. I'm using the latest version. I am also using this utility for other functions and it works well, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work in this instance.

Comment: @MrRoy: you are redirecting its stdout elsewhere and it works? In those instances, are you also executing the `qfarm` command? Or something else?

Comment: I am using Sysinternal's PSLIST, which outputs a list of processes, and redirect the stdout to a string. It works without any issue. I also use PSEXEC elsewhere to invoke commands on remote machines, but I do not redirect the output.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to have the.

```
p.WaitForExit()
```

method after the line where you read the output. Here is an explanation from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is not correct. The `ReadToEnd()` method will block until the end of the stream is reached. Adding a call (to anything) _after_ the call to `ReadToEnd()` has no effect on what `ReadToEnd()` returns.

Comment: You are correct, the original line didn't have the WaitForExit before the call to read the stream.